# Cascade DropDown not firing OnSelectIndexChanged event

Tags: c#, asp.net, dropdown

I have a page with two DropDowns.

```
<div class="block-container">
    <div class="fieldItem" style="margin-top: 10px;">
        <asp:Label ID="pistaServizioLabel" runat="server">PISTA/FAMIGLIA SERVIZIO </asp:Label>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="pistaServizio" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="pistaServizio_SelectedIndexChanged" Style="width: auto;" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true">
            <asp:ListItem Text="Selezionare un valore" Value="" />
            <asp:ListItem Text="Mobile" Value="Mobile" />
        </asp:DropDownList>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="block-container">
    <div class="fieldItem" style="margin-top: 10px;">
        <asp:Label ID="ambitoLabel" runat="server">AMBITO </asp:Label>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ambito" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectIndexChanged="ambito_SelectedIndexChanged" Style="width: auto;" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true">
        </asp:DropDownList>
    </div>
</div>
```

On the first one, when you select a value, the OnSelectIndexChanged event (pistaServizio_SelectedIndexChanged) is correctly firing and it's populating the second DropDown with several ListItems.

So, after PostBack, you have the second DropDown populated, but if you select a value from it, it's not firing its OnSelectIndexChanged event (ambito_SelectedIndexChanged).. It should log something but nothing happens

Here the two eventhandlers

```
protected void pistaServizio_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    logger.LogDebug("pistaServizio_SelectedIndexChanged"); 
    if (pistaServizio.SelectedValue != "")
    {
        uploadContainer.Visible = true;
        ambito.Items.Clear();
        ambito.Items.Add(new ListItem("Seleziona un valore", ""));
        ambito.Items.Add(new ListItem("Test", "Test"));
    }
    else
    {
        uploadContainer.Visible = false;
        ambito.Items.Clear();
    }
}

protected void ambito_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    logger.LogDebug("ambito_SelectedIndexChanged");
}
```

Are there any suggestions about why the second one is not firing? Thanks

**EDIT**

I've noticed that the problem is not the cascade event, but the second DropDown. 
I've added two list items to it

```
 <asp:Label ID="ambitoLabel" runat="server">AMBITO </asp:Label>
<asp:DropDownList ID="ambito" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectIndexChanged="ambito_SelectedIndexChanged" Style="width: auto;" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem Text="Selezionare un valore" Value="" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="Test" Value="Test" />
</asp:DropDownList>
```

So I'm ignoring the first DropDown and I select directly a value from the second one. 
Also in this case, the ambito_SelectedIndexChanged is not firing

Comment: Does it do a postback, and just not run the handler, or does the postback not even occur?

Comment: It's doing the postback

Comment: And if you put a breakpoint on logger.LogDebug is it hitting that breakpoint?  ALso, web forms uses a trick for controls that auto postback from javascript... the __EVENTTARGET and __EVENTARGUMENT form variables contains the control name and event name that the server should run (two underscores) and so you could check that to make sure the web form is properly recognizing the postback by the drop down.  Sometimes that is the cause...  Also, is there an update panel involved?

Comment: Thanks for your time. It's not hitting the logger.LogDebug breakpoint and I'm not using any updatepanel. The Postback is being done as I logged the boolean isPostBack and is saying True

Comment: __EVENTTARGET has the correct value ct100$MainContent$ambito

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, solved. There was something broken behind the code. I ended deleting the "ambito" DropDown, created a new one, and everything is woking fine now. Thanks